# Linear transformation linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let T: $\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^3$ be defined by:

$$T\left(
 \begin{bmatrix}
    x    \\
    y  \\
    z
  \end{bmatrix} \right) = \begin{bmatrix}
    x - y + 2z \\
    2x + 3y - z \\
    -x +2y -2z
  \end{bmatrix} 
$$

a) Show that T is a linear transformation:

I think i can rewrite this as

$T[x,y,z] = T[x - y + 2z, 2x + 3y - z, -x + 2y - 2z]$

Let $u = [u_1, u_2, u_3]$ and $v = [v_1, v_2, v_3]$ where

$u,v, \in \mathbb R^3$, let $r \in \mathbb R$

i) T(u + v) = $T([u_1+v_1, u_2 + v_2, u_3 + v_3])$

$= [(u_1 - u_2 + 2u_3 + v_1 - v_2 + 2v_3, 2u_1 + 3u_2 - u_3 + 2v_1 + 3v_2 - v_3, -u_1 + 2u_2 - 2u_3 -v_1 + 2v_2 - 2v_3]$

$= T([u_1,u_2,u_3]) + T([v_1,v_2,v_3]) = T(u) + T(v)$

ii) T(ru) = $T[ru_1, ru_2, ru_3]$

$= [ru_2 - ru_2 + 2ru_3, 2ru_1 + 3ru_2 - ru_3, -ru_1 + 2ru_2 - 2ru_3]$

$ r[u_1 - u_2 + 2u_3, 2u_1 + 3u_2 - u_3, -u_1 + 2u_2 - 2u_3]$

= $rT(u)$

b) Find the matrix representation of T:

$$
 \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & -1 & 2    \\
    2 & 3 & -1  \\
    -1 & 2 & -2
  \end{bmatrix}
$$

c) Determine if T is invertible and, if it is, give a formula for $T^{−1}$

$$T^{-1} \left(
 \begin{bmatrix}
    x    \\
    y  \\
    z
  \end{bmatrix} \right) =
 \begin{bmatrix}
    -\frac{4}{5}x +  \frac{2}{5} y  -1 z    \\
    x + z  \\
    \frac{7}{5}x - \frac{1}{5}y + z
  \end{bmatrix}
$$

.
d) Determine whether or not T is one-to-one and onto.

Idk

I'm just following the definition I'm not sure if im right. Could someone check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i) T(u + v) = $T([u_1+v_1, u_2 + v_2, u_3 + v_3])$
>
> $= [(u_1 - u_2 + 2u_3 + v_1 - v_2 + 2v_3, 2u_1 + 3u_2 - u_3 + 2v_1 + 3v_2 - v_3, -u_1 + 2u_2 - 2u_3 -v_1 + 2v_2 - 2v_3]$
>
> $= \color{red}{T(T[u_1,u_2,u_3])} = T(u) + T(v)$

You may mean well, but this is written in a strange way (definitely the part in red).

You want to show that $T(u+v)=T(u)+T(v)$, I would write it like this:
$$\begin{align}
T(u+v) & = \begin{bmatrix}
    u_1+v_1 - (u_2+v_2) + 2(u_3+v_3) \\
    2(u_1+v_1) + 3(u_2+v_2) - (u_3+v_3) \\
    -(u_1+v_1) +2(u_2+v_2) -2(u_3+v_3)
  \end{bmatrix} \\[10pt]
& = \begin{bmatrix}
    u_1- u_2 + 2u_3 \\
    2u_1 + 3u_2 - u_3+ \\
    -u_1 +2u_2 -2u_3
  \end{bmatrix}+
\begin{bmatrix}
    v_1- v_2 + 2v_3 \\
    2v_1 + 3v_2 - v_3+ \\
    -v_1 +2v_2 -2v_3
  \end{bmatrix}\\[10pt]
& = T(u)+T(v)
\end{align}$$

> ii) T(ru) = $T[ru_1, ru_2, ru_3]$
>
> $= [r\color{red}{u_2} - ru_2 + 2ru_3, 2ru_1 + 3ru_2 - ru_3, -ru_1 + 2ru_2 - 2ru_3]$
>
> $ r[\color{red}{u_2} - u_2 + 2u_3, 2u_1 + 3u_2 - u_3, -u_1 + 2u_2 - 2u_3]$

Good, apart from a small typo in red (should be $\color{green}{u_1}$).

> b) Find the matrix representation of T:
>
> $$ \begin{bmatrix}
>     1 & -1 & 2    \\
>     2 & 3 & -1  \\
>     -1 & 2 & -2
>   \end{bmatrix}$$

Correct!

> c) Determine if T is invertible and, if it is, give a formula for $T^{−1}$
>
> $$T^{-1} \left(
>  \begin{bmatrix}
>     x    \\
>     y  \\
>     z
>   \end{bmatrix} \right) =
>  \begin{bmatrix}
>     -\frac{4}{5}x +  \frac{2}{5} y  -1 z    \\
>     \color{red}{x - z}  \\
>     \frac{7}{5}x - \frac{1}{5}y + z
>   \end{bmatrix}
> $$

Almost, the part in red should be $\color{green}{x + z}$.

> d) Determine whether or not T is one-to-one and onto.

Since $T$ is invertible (see part c), it is bijective and thus surely *one-to-one* and *onto*.

Comment: Thank you. Could you look at d). I like ur way much better for a)

Comment: @user349557 I was adding after your edit; answer updated.

Comment: What does it mean to be one-to-one and onto, and what do u mean bijective?

Comment: @user349557 If you don't know what these terms mean, you should first check your course notes and/or look up the definitions. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection,_injection_and_surjection) or for the specific context of linear transformations, [this pdf-document](http://home.apu.edu/~bmathews/290f09/onetoone.pdf) is nice as well.